# special XML to wordpress posts

Tags: seo, xml

I've got a difficult one: One of our customers have lots of XML files and wants to be created as posts for SEO reasons.

How can I import XML and convert them to posts automatically? I've seen plugins but it's way to much time to just import a serie of XML files with multiple rows.

How is the structure in the XML:

```
<Row>
<SRI_ID></SRI_ID>
<Author></Author>
<Mailing_Address></Mailing_address>
<Title></Title>
<Abstract></abstract>
<Source></Source>
</Row>
```

Answer (score -2):

turbo csv is a great plugin, i always use it on my projects :

- You convert your xml to csv (much easier to manage posts after)
- the plugin converts the csv to a post and you could even populate custom fields